# g++ and clang++ different behaviour with variable template and SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, template-variables

Another question of type "who's right between g++ and clang++?" for C++ standard gurus.

Suppose we want apply SFINAE to a variable template to enable the variable only if the template type fulfill a certain condition.

By example: enable `bar` if (and only if) the template type has a `foo()` method with a given signature.

Using SFINAE through an additional template type with default value

```
template <typename T, typename = decltype(T::foo())>
static constexpr int bar = 1;
```

works for both g++ and clang++ but has a problem: can be hijacked explicating the second template type

So

```
int i = bar<int>;
```

gives a compilation error where

```
int i = bar<int, void>;
```

compile without problem.

So, from the bottom of my ignorance about SFINAE, I've tried enabling/disabling the type of the same variable:

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr decltype(T::foo(), int{}) bar = 2;
```

Surprise: this works (compile) for g++ but clang++ doesn't accept it and give the following error

```
tmp_003-14,gcc,clang.cpp:8:30: error: no member named 'foo' in 'without_foo'
static constexpr decltype(T::foo(), int{}) bar = 2;
                          ~~~^
```

The question, as usual, is: who's right ? g++ or clang++ ?

In other words: according the C++14 standard, SFINAE can be used over the type of a variable template ?

The following is a full example to play with

```
#include <type_traits>

// works with both g++ and clang++
//template <typename T, typename = decltype(T::foo())>
//static constexpr int bar = 1;

// works with g++ but clang++ gives a compilation error
template <typename T>
static constexpr decltype(T::foo(), int{}) bar = 2;

struct with_foo
 { static constexpr int foo () { return 0; } };

struct without_foo
 { };

template <typename T>
constexpr auto exist_bar_helper (int) -> decltype(bar<T>, std::true_type{});

template <typename T>
constexpr std::false_type exist_bar_helper (...);

template <typename T>
constexpr auto exist_bar ()
 { return decltype(exist_bar_helper<T>(0)){}; }

int main ()
 {
   static_assert( true == exist_bar<with_foo>(), "!" );
   static_assert( false == exist_bar<without_foo>(), "!" );
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure your first snippet runs sfinae and not hard error? In case of function templates it wouldn't...

Comment: I hope `T::foo()` doesn't have a return type `R` with an overloaded `operator,(R,int)`...

Comment: I mean `template <class T, decltype(T::foo ()) * = nullptr>` would invoke sfinae this one I'm not so sure...

Comment: @W.F. - You're making me come doubts. Not sure to understand your question. Do you mean: can we define it SFINAE if there isn't an alternative? In this case, yes, I suppose we can define another, specular, variable `bar` that is defined if (and only if) the first one isn't defined.

Comment: @aschepler - yes, I hope the same. I admit: my example isn't really perfect.

Comment: @max66 yes I'm not sure about template variables either just trying to generalize by finding the common aspects...

Comment: The absence of a clear definition of "immediate context" strikes again. Nobody knows for sure. (See core issue 1844.)

Answer (score -1):

Let's analyze what's happening here:

My initial assumption is that this looks like a clang missinterpretation. It isn't able to go back in the resolution tree when `bar` is not resolved properly.

First, to be sure that the problem is in `bar`, we can do this:

```
template <typename T>
constexpr auto exist_bar_helper(int) -> decltype(void(T::foo()), std::true_type{});
```

It works properly (SFINAE is doing its job).

Now, let's change your code to check if nested failed resolutions are wrapped by outer SFINAE context. After changing `bar` to be a function:

```
template <typename T>
static constexpr decltype(void(T::foo()), int{}) bar();
```

It still works properly, cool. Then, I would assume that any incorrect resolution inside our `decltype` will go back and make the function resolve to the SFINAE fallback (std::false_type)... but nope.

This is what GCC does:

```
exist_bar -> exists_bar_helper -> bar (woops) -> no worries, i have alternatives
          -> exists_bar_helper(...) -> false
```

This is what CLANG does:

```
exist_bar -> exists_bar_helper -> bar (woops) // oh no
// I cannot access that var, this is unrecoverable error AAAAAAAA
```

It takes it so seriously that forgets about the fallback in the upper context.

Long story short: don't SFINAE on templated variables, SFINAE its a compiler hack by itself and can behave in strange ways when compilers try to be "too smart"